# My div is overlaps to the bootstrap header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i inserted a div in between my text and my header picture. please can anyone help me. i would be grateful. When i placed the div it goes to the back of the text and moves up. what can i do.I am finding it hard to add the code file. but this is the div overlapping
MY JSFIDDLE IS HERE [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/timiosaze/6dLupf4e/4/)

```css
/*REVEAL LINK*/
.revela {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 100px;

 background-color: #8080ff;
}
.button, .button:focus {
 background-color: black;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button:hover {
 background-color: #8080ff; 
 border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*IMAGE DESIGN*/
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

 /*margin-top: -50px;*/

}
.exampleClass {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
/*NAVBAR*/
nav {
 width: 100%;
}


/*body { 
 padding-top: 70px; 
}*/
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  top: calc(100% + 9px);
}
.navbar {

 padding: 10px 0;
 margin:0;
 border-radius:0;
 border:none;
 width: 100% !important;
 /*z-index: 1;*/
 font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}
.navbar-default{
 background-color: #8080ff;
 width: 100% !important; 
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header > a, .navbar-default .navbar-header > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-header > a:hover {
 color:white;
 font-size: 2em;
}
.navbar-header button {
 border:none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: white;
 transition: color 0.5s;
 font-size: 1.1em;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
 color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.list:after {
 content: "";
 display:block;
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
 transform: scale(0);
 transition: transform 0.8s ease-in;
 transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.list:hover:after {
 transform:scaleX(1);
}
/*ABOUT COMPANY*/
.works {
 margin:30px 50px;
}  

.history, .about{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 color:black;
}
.history{
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.about {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Allamit | Agric Engineering</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400i" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/allamit.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class= "container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-demo">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbrand">ALLAMIT</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-demo">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="list"><a href="Director/company_profile.html">ABOUT</a></li>
     <li class="list"><a href="machine_gallery/feed_mixer_hammer_mill.html">COMPANY WORKS</a></li>
     <li class="list"><a href="about/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>        
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>

</nav>  

<div class="col-xs-12 exampleClass">
 <img class="image" src="https://s18.postimg.org/q7qolxsmx/garri_processing.jpg">

</div>
<div class="revela">
 <a class="button" href="revealmaster/index.html">Click Here For A Presentation About The Website</a>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="works">
 <!-- <div class="col-lg-12"> -->
  <h2 class="history">Our Company History</h2>
  <p class="about"> The company was incorporated February 1999 (RC 350443). Allamit (Nig). Limited is one of the eminent manufacturers and exporters of quality agricultural and industrial machines in Nigeria. Our company specializes in research and development and promotion of the following machines ... <a class="more" class="more" href="Director/company_profile.html">Read More</a></p>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/allamit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

this is the div when the picture is removed. it seems the div goes under the bootstrap header
[image]
This is the div class revela 
[image]

Comment: Provide the proper code

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with html and css in a snippet (not in a picture)

Comment: i have added the code. please any help

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Also, [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: please can you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into your code, there is a floating happen inside your `<div class="revela">` tag,

So you just need to add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` before `<div class="revela">` tag.

So it will look something like:

[image]

Hope this may help you.